# Tricky Probability! (or impossible)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that we have 3 independent events (Students that they are attending lectures) 
`P(a) = .10 P(b) = .17 and P(c) = .23` 
What is the probability that during a school day that two of these events (students) are attending the lessons while a third is not.

I am asking if it's possible to calculate this, as there is no info given about who is attending what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If events are Independent, Then $P(A) = .10\;,$ Then $P(\bar{A}) = 1-P(A) = .90$

similarly $P(B) = .17\;,$ Then $P(\bar{B}) = .87$ Similarly $P(C) = .23\;,$ Then $P(\bar{B}) = .77$

So $$\bf{P(exactly\; 2 \; student\; attending \; lession)}$$

$$ = P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(\bar{C})+P(A)\cdot P(\bar{B})\cdot P(C)+P(\bar{A})\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C)$$

$$ = 0.10\times 0.17\times 0.77+0.10\times 0.87\times 0.23+0.90\times 0.17\times 0.77 = 0.15091$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If the events were not independent, would this be possible to calculate? Shouldn't we subtract the union between these three elements?

Comment: Then we will use principle of Inclusion-exclusion.